# gnome-screenshot does not work from VS Code debugger, but works fine without debugger

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debug, gnome-screenshot

Fresh Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS installation, VS Code, python 3.10.12.
The following python script:

```
tmpFilename = '.screenshot%s.png' % (datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m%d_%H-%M-%S-%f'))
subprocess.call(['gnome-screenshot', '-f', tmpFilename])
```

When I debug this script it gives a lot of errors

```
Failed to load module: /home/miranda/snap/code/common/.cache/gio-modules libgiolibproxy.so
gnome-screenshot: symbol lookup error: /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined symbol: __libc_pthread_init, version GLIBC_PRIVATE
/snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxy.so.1)
Failed to load module: /home/miranda/snap/code/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiolibproxy.so
gnome-screenshot: symbol lookup error: /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined symbol: __libc_pthread_init, version GLIBC_PRIVATE
```

But if I run the python script without VS Code debugger, from a bash terminal window, everything works fine.

Comment: Is it your script?  `gnome-screenshot` was the default for older releases of GNOME, but has replaced and isn't included by default for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop (https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/jammy/daily-live/current/jammy-desktop-amd64.manifest) as only a *community* supported package on releases >20.04 or beyond *focal*.

Comment: I wonder if this is relevant [Undefined Symbol Error while trying to launch GUI Apps from a Snap Installed VSCode Built-in Terminal #179274](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/179274). See also [Java: symbol lookup error: /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined symbol: __libc_pthread_init, version GLIBC_PRIVATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75921414/java-symbol-lookup-error-snap-core20-current-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libpthread)

Comment: @guiverc No, this is not my code.
`from PIL import ImageGrab`
ImageGrab function use it. I can not debug my code because of that.
Any other recommendation to catch an area from the screen?